# Are all the false names used by Dean Winchester musicians' names?

Tags: supernatural

Whenever Dean Winchester pretends to be a policeman, a FBI agent or the like, he'll give a false name. I distinctly remember him introducing himself and his brother as Agent Angus and Agent Young in an occasion, and himself alone as Ian Anderson in another.

Does he only uses musicians' names, or are there other names?

What about Sam?

Also, has anybody kept a list of those names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The Supernatural wikia has a list of [Aliases](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Aliases). There are plenty of examples of fake names being given that aren't famous musicians, but they're usually references to other aspects of popular culture. As an example, S01E03, where they introduce themselves as Agents Ford and Hamill, which is a reference to actors Harrison Ford and Mark Hamill from Star Wars.